# ManualResetEvent - Backlog of events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, .net-4.0

Im having some issues around the ManualResetEvent and a backlog of events. My application is subscribing to messages then running a long task.

The issue I have is that I am receiving more messages than I can process. Task is taking around 5s to process but im receiving a new message every 2-3s.

Ideally what I want to do is ignore any new events until i've finished processing the task then start 'listening' again. At present I appear to be backlogging the events in order of being received and processed. As you can imagine after a couple of hours the message being processed is very old.

I cannot run the long running task from multiple threads.

Maybe I require some kind of queing mechanism then clear the last message (Last On First Off) and delete the queue?

Any ideas?

Im also calling the ManualResetEvent.Set() at the end of the long running process - from my research I understand this is correct? Should I Reset() at the beginning of the long running task to caused the thread to block then Set() at the end?

Comment: Why not: Receive message -> Unsubscribe -> process message -> resubscribe ?

Comment: Hi, I did think of that but subscribe/unsubscribe is provided by 3rd party and threw an error. I will contact them but was hoping as a quick woerkaround I could create a queue then take the top one.

Comment: I've started using a background thread to do the work and added logic `if(bw.IsBusy != true) do_work, else continue listening for next subscription `

Answer (score 1):

Create a circular buffer that you treat as a LIFO queue (a stack). So, say you want a maximum of 10 entries in the queue:

```
const int MaxItems = 10;
Item[] theQueue = new Item[];
int insertPoint = 0;
object myLock = new object();
// initialize the array to all NULL.

void Enqueue(Item t)
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
        theQueue[insertPoint] = t;
        insertPoint = (insertPoint+1) % 10;
    }
}

Item Dequeue()
{
    lock (myLock)
    {
        int takeFrom = insertPoint-1;
        if (takeFrom < 0)
            takeFrom = MaxItems-1;
        if (theQueue[takeFrom] != null)
        {
            var rslt = theQueue[takeFrom];
            insertPoint = takeFrom;
            return rslt;
        }
        // queue is empty. Either return null or throw an exception.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course you'll want to wrap that all up into a nice object. But that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

**How about this:**

At any given time, you have one message being processed, and one message waiting to be processed.

When you receive a new message, you overwrite the message waiting to be processed.

Your processing thread waits until there is a message waiting to be processed, then mark it as being processed, processes it, then starts again.

Add some syncing logic, and you get this code:

```
private object _sync = new object();
private Message _beingProcessed;
private Message _waitingToBeProcesssed;

public void OnMessageReceived(Message message)
{
    lock(sync)
    {
        _waitingToBeProcesssed = message;
        Monitor.Pulse(sync);
    }
}

public void DoWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            while (_waitingToBeProcesssed == null)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(sync);
            }

            _beingProcessed = _waitingToBeProcesssed;
            _waitingToBeProcesssed = null;
        }

        Process(_beingProcessed); //Do the actual work
    }
}
```